# Jquery Ajax couldn't get the current focused input element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have form that has two kinds of input field, 1) input field for ID, 2) input field for name. I already have a mysql database with a table filled with ID and name data. What I want to do is when I type an ID number in the input field for ID, and when it loses focus, the jquery script will automatically fill the input field for name according to the ID number in the database.
So my html input form is something like this:

html :

```
<input type='text' name='id' class='input_id'>
<input type='text' name='name' class='input_name'>
<br>
<input type='text' name='id'>
<input type='text' name='name'>
```

jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
    $('.input_id').blur(function() {
        $.post('search_name.php',
        {
            id: $('.input_id').val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.input_name').val(data);
        });
    });
});
```

php (search_name.php) code :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$name = $result['name'];

echo $name;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is in one form, I will have 20 rows of ID and name input field, how do I modify my jquery script so that when ID input field in row 1 loses focus, it will only auto-fill name input field in row 1, the one in row 2 will only auto-fill name input field in row 2 and so on, rather than writing the same script 20 times.

I tried using traversing method such as (this) and (next), but I could not seem to get it working. I also tried using (:focus) method too, I am not sure whether I use it wrongly or it is not meant for this.

All suggestions are welcomed.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are siblings, use this and next()

```
$('.input_id').blur(function() {
    var inp = $(this);
    $.post('search_name.php',
    {
        id: inp.val()
    },
    function(data) {
        inp.next('.input_name').val(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: What? how come it works when you convert $(this) into a var, I tried this too but without changing $(this) into var, and it doesn't work.. Do you mind elaborate this matter ?? Thank you very much.

Comment: Where did you try to do it with `$(this)` and it did not work? In the Ajax call back? The scope of this in the success function is not the same outside of it. `console.log(this);` will show that.